# Can't understand about pytorch tensor broadcast

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following code:

```
import torch
d = 2
n = 50
X = torch.randn(n,d)
z = torch.tensor([[-1.0], [2.0]])
y = X @ z
X.size()
z.size()
y.size()
```

The output is:

```
torch.Size([50, 2])
torch.Size([2, 1])
torch.Size([50, 1])
```

My question is, why after broadcasting, the size of the result `y` is `[50,1]` rather than `[50,2]`, I think it should be `[50,2]`, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` is not broadcasting but multiplication.

> In python 3.5, the `@` operator was introduced for matrix
> multiplication, following [PEP465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/). This is implemented e.g. in `numpy`
> as the `matmul` operator.

So the size of `y` is fine.

multiply a matrix of size `[50,2]` with a vector of size `[2,1]` will output a vector of size `[50,1]`.

An example showing it more clearly is:

```
import torch
xx = torch.ones(3, 2)
zz = torch.tensor([[-1.0], [2.0]])
yy = xx @ zz

print(xx)
print(zz)
print(yy)


# tensor([[1., 1.],
#         [1., 1.],
#         [1., 1.]])
# tensor([[-1.],
#         [ 2.]])
# tensor([[1.],
#         [1.],
#         [1.]])
```

As you can see the third output is indeed just the multiplication of the 2 tensors.

If you wish to do broadcasting I recommend that you will refer to https://medium.com/ai%C2%B3-theory-practice-business/understanding-broadcasting-in-pytorch-ca9e9533f05f

Comment: Thank you, I can only accept after 3 minutes. By the way, how can I @ you when there is a space in your name? a.k.a between "Jin" and "Kim" there is a space.@Gwang-Jin Kim